# string to tuple swift

Tags: swift, xcode, string

I'm trying to import data from a text file. I can read the file, but I don't know how to parse the `String` to something else, e.g. tuple.

The data in the file (`text.txt`) is formatted as pixels and their colors

```
(((0, 0), (1, 0), (2, 0), (3, 0), (4, 0), (5, 0)),((63479, 62451, 63479), (63479, 62451, 63479), (63479, 62451, 63479), (63479, 62451, 63479), (63479, 62451, 63479))
```

Here's my code so far:

```
//
//  ViewController.swift

import Cocoa

class ViewController: NSViewController {

    @IBAction func passPix(_ sender: Any) {
        let fileURL = "/Users/IMac/Desktop/text.txt"
        var inString = ("Pix+Col")
        do {
            inString = try String(contentsOfFile: fileURL, encoding:String.Encoding.utf8)

        } catch let error as NSError {
            print("Failed reading from URL: \(fileURL), Error: " + error.localizedDescription)
        }

        print(inString)
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you explain in more detail the format of the file?

Comment: plain simple text utf8 with .txt end. Inside two closed brackets ()(), inside brackets numbers (in brackets too). but problem isn't in the file, swift see string! I just do not do anything with this string

Comment: Well what do those numbers mean?

Comment: What's the layout of the numbers and their significance?

Comment: coordinate x an y of pixel and its's color in RGB format

Comment: So is it: `(((x1, y1), (x2, y2), ..., (xn, yn)), ((r1, g1, b1), (r2, g2, b), ..., (rn, gn, bn))`?

Comment: exactly! this is picture data from .png file

Comment: I can write a parser for it guess, but rrally why is in such a nonsensical format? This is significantly worse than bitmap, the worst of the image formats.  2/5ths of the numbers is redundant coordinates, and some senseless amount more is wasted in brackets

Comment: Why don't you just load the PNG file directly?

Comment: far far away I made a plotter which must paint pictures with brash. Then I make an applescript which recalculate png or jpg to the G-codes. Problem is that applescript very slow try to stretch primitives at the array string. Now I have a part with applescript which generate string from picture and I need a swift-based part which will calculate G-code.

Comment: OK, again. sorry. I have a plotter. Plotter works at G-Codes. Programm prepare Gcodes in next method: 1) make from picture array string 2) collect all similar colors in one string---> as result have several strings with pixels coordinates. 3) trying to add in strings circles or another figures (for example coordinates (0,1) (0,2) (0,3) mean line)       4) make G-code

Comment: And why must this use this convoluted string format, and just PNG?

Comment: actually, because I do not know how make it in another way.

Comment: So this is an example of an [xy problem](http://xyproblem.info). I suggest you abandon this convoluted approach and open a new question, asking how to use an imagine (PNG or otherwise) to achieve *what you're actually trying to accomplish*

Comment: You do not right. You ask me my and I tell. But question is very simple: how can I work with this string in swift?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my take on it. Basically you replace the round brackets with square brackets in your original String, convert it to a JSON object and then traverse the resulting JSON object as you see fit :

```
let s = "(((0, 0), (1, 0), (2, 0), (3, 0), (4, 0)),((63479, 62451, 63479), (63479, 62451, 63479), (63479, 62451, 63479), (63479, 62451, 63479), (63479, 62451, 63479)))"

var js = String(s.characters.map { $0 == "(" ? "[" : $0 })
js = String(js.characters.map { $0 == ")" ? "]" : $0 })

var data = js.data(using: .utf8)
let json = try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!) as! [Any]

let coords = json[0] as! [Any]
let rgbs = json[1] as! [Any]

for (i, coord) in coords.enumerated() {
    print ("\(coord) - \(rgbs[i])")
}
```

The output will be something like this:

```
[0, 0] - [63479, 62451, 63479]
[1, 0] - [63479, 62451, 63479]
[2, 0] - [63479, 62451, 63479]
[3, 0] - [63479, 62451, 63479]
[4, 0] - [63479, 62451, 63479]
```

So, at each iteration you get one array with the x,y coordinates and another one with the r,g,b color values of the pixel. You could easily convert them to tuples but I see little need to do so at this point.

Comment: thanks, try to use your code.  actually, I going to collect all similar coloured pixels in one string like [0,0], [0,1], [0,2] - [r,g,b]   [2,1] [2,2] [2,3] - [r1,g1,b1]

Comment: @AlekSzczęsnowicz : I think it would be best to ask another question, let's keep this one clean for future reference.